# Why is online learning 'much faster' than full-batch? - Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network

I do not really understand because it is the same calculation that is done. Or maybe I do not understand the batching really well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the definition of full-batch and online learning. If full-batch is defined as n > 1 and online learning is defined as n = 1, then full-batch will be slower than online. Additional time is required to process additional data.